# ヘルプセンター: 「製品サポートとしてこのサイトを使ってもよいですか？」の内容を改善したい

Tags: 討議, 完了, ヘルプ

ヘルプセンターの [製品サポートとしてこのサイトを使ってもよいですか？](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/product-support) に記載の内容に則って、実際にスタックオーバーフローを質問の投稿先に指定されているWebサイトがいくつかあるようですが、リンク元での記載が不十分なのか、プログラミングとはあまり関係の無い製品サポート寄りの質問まで投稿されている例がいくつかあります。

掲載しているサイトの例:

- [aiboデベロッパープログラム - aibo](http://aibo.sony.jp/developer/)
- [サポート - Spresense](https://developer.sony.com/ja/develop/spresense/support)

審査等が無ければ強制する事も出来ないので、実際に守られるかは掲載するサイト側の対応に委ねられますが、少なくとも「**リンク先(スタック・オーバーフロー)は外部サイト**」であることを明記してもらいたく、[ヘルプ](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/product-support) にも念のため追記した方がよいのでは？と思っています。

---

外部サイトへの注意書きの例:

> [外部サイトにリンクしています。 | 政府広報オンライン](https://www.gov-online.go.jp/tokusyu/korei_syohisya/ext/details_01.html)
>
> - リンク先のウェブサイトは、内閣府のウェブサイトではなく、内閣府の管理下にはないものです。
> - リンク先のウェブサイトについては、リンク先の組織・団体等にご確認ください。

Answer (score 1):

ヘルプセンターは通常グローバルで統一されていますが、[製品サポートとしてこのサイトを使ってもよいですか？](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/product-support)のページは日本ローカルでアップデートをすることになりました。コミュニティで改善したいと思います。

以下、ご編集ください。（[英語はご参考として](https://stackoverflow.com/help/product-support)）

---

「自分たちの製品をサポートするにはど‌​うすればスタック・オーバーフローをうまく活用できますか？」といった質問が、プロダクト開発チームから数多く寄せられています。

スタック・オーバーフローはテクニカルサポートのプラットフォームとして大変有効に機能するためこのような活用を歓迎しています。以下のガイドラインに従って頂ければ、開発チーム、プロダクトユーザー、そしてスタック・オーバーフロー、全員のためになると考えます。

スタック・オーバーフローはプログラマーが互いに助け合うQ&Aサイトです。製品開発チームもその一員です。製品がリリース直後でなければ既に質問があるかもしれませんし、製品向けの[タグ](/tags)が存在する可能性もあります。また、サイト上で製品名やキーワードで[検索](/search)し、関連する質問や回答を見つけることも出来るでしょう。質問に回答し、既に良い回答が書かれていればその回答にプラス投票してください。自分の製品以外についても回答できる質問を探してみるのも良いでしょう。サイトに参加し、優れた質問や回答のコツを学んでください。そしてコメントや編集等を可能にする権限を得るためにも信用度を獲得して下さい。

スタック・オーバーフローは製品サポートの一助にはなりますが、当コミュニティが全てをカバーすることはできません。開発チームにしか解決できない問題もあるため、そのサポートをスタック・オーバーフローへ案内すると互いの不満になる恐れがあります。そのような状況を避けるため、ユーザーへ下記のようなガイダンスを周知してください：

**「製品サポート」と「スタック・オーバーフロー」はそれぞれ別のサイトであることを明示してください**

**質問の内容に応じて適切な投稿先を案内してください**

> - **製品サポート向けの質問**
>
>   - 「このエラーは恐らくバグによるものだと思います」
>   - 「意見/要望があります」
>   - 「何故○○なのですか？」
>   - 「○○のリリースはいつになりそうですか？」
> - **スタック・オーバーフロー向けの質問**
>
>   - 「どうすれば○○できますか？」（どのタグを使用すべきかも指定すること - 最低限のタグとして、製品名とプログラミング言語を付けてもらうことをお勧めします）
>   - 「このエラーの原因は何でしょうか？」

出来るだけサイト上の活動をウォッチしてください。スタック・オーバーフローには毎日数多く質問が寄せられ回答されます。迅速に対応するためには、製品のタグが付いた質問をウォッチし、正確にタグ付けされていない質問を見つけて改善し、回答をレビューし編集することが必要です。また、スタック・オーバーフローはユーザーによって管理・運用されている事を忘れないで下さい。サイト上で製品ユーザーのみなさまに良い体験をして頂くには、当サイトの仕組みや使い方に慣れていない方への案内・サポートが不可欠です。

スタック・オーバーフローは質問と回答が多くのプログラマーの目と手によって整理・改善されていく場所です。そして、スタック・オーバーフローはあなたの製品に関する質問や回答を歓迎します。

なお、このガイドラインについて質問がある場合、もしくは製品向けのタグ作成や管理にサポートが必要な場合、[当社にご連絡](/contact)ください。可能な限りお手伝いさせて頂きます。

---

関連：[Is it acceptable to use Stack Overflow as a Q&A for a specific product? - Meta Stack Overflow](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/253852/7493042)