# ヘルプセンターの「スタック・オーバーフロー」と「Stack Overflow」の表記ゆれを統一したい

Tags: 機能の要求, 完了, ヘルプ

### 提案内容

ヘルプセンターでは [ja.stackoverflow.com](https://ja.stackoverflow.com) を指して以下の 2 つの表記が使われています:

- スタック・オーバーフロー
- Stack Overflow

現在の [ja.stackoverflow.com](https://ja.stackoverflow.com) ではタイトルに「スタック・オーバーフロー」を用いています。また、 Stack Overflow は [stackoverflow.com](https://stackoverflow.com) のタイトルと表記が重複しており、どちらを指しているかについて読み手を混乱させてしまう可能性があります。そこで、 **Stack Overflow をスタック・オーバーフローへ変更**し、この表記ゆれを統一することを提案します。

Stack Overflow と表記されているヘルプのページは以下のとおりです:

- [製品サポートとしてこのサイトを使ってもよいですか？](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/product-support)
- [ここではどのようなトピックについて質問できますか？](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)
- [最小限の・自己完結した・確認可能なサンプルコードの書き方](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

---

### 関連投稿

- [ブランド展開戦略: 「日本語版」と言わない](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/1433/32986)

Answer (score 3):

提案そのものについては 賛成 です。

下記の二つは「内容を改善しましょう」という別のメタ投稿がされており、この中で「スタック・オーバーフロー」表記に揃えられているので、後は反映待ちの状態です。

- [「製品サポートとしてこのサイトを使ってもよいですか？」の内容を改善したい](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/3134)
- [「最小限の・自己完結した・確認可能なサンプルコードの書き方」を改善したい](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/3013)

「ここではどのような～」のページも表記を揃えるだけならモデレーター権限で直接編集できるのですが、["改善待ち"が無くなっていたり](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/3158)、全体的な文面も改善の余地ありなのかなと個人的には思います。

追記@2020/06/16
ひとまず表記ゆれを先に揃えました！
全体的な文面の改善については[こちら](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/1389/14055)をご覧くださいませ。

Comment: 「製品サポートとして〜」と「最小限の・自己完結〜」は反映完了いたしました。